# Value disappears from data in gridview after button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying yo create a site using ASP.NET with C#.

I created a gridview in which i placed a textbox and a dropdown in template fields.

I need to read the text from the textbox and the selected value from the dropdown when a button is pressed.

When I try to read the data I only see that the textbox's text is "" and that the dropdown's value is the default value, no matter what the user has chosen.

This is my ASP code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdArticles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GrdArticles_RowCommand" Width="1037px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="כותרת" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="תיאור" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="userName" HeaderText="מעלה המאמר" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="courseName" HeaderText="קורס" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="userID" HeaderText="userID" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="courseID" HeaderText="courseID" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="facultyID" HeaderText="facultyID" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rank" HeaderText="דירוג ממוצע" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="דירוג משתמש">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpRank">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="הערות">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtComments" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:ButtonField Text="דרג" CommandName="rank" />
        <asp:ButtonField Text="הוסף הערות" CommandName="addComments" />
        <asp:ButtonField Text="הורד" CommandName="download" />
        <asp:ButtonField Text="הצג הערות" CommandName="showComments" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And this is my C# code:

```
protected void GrdArticles_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow selectedRow = grdArticles.Rows[index];
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)selectedRow.FindControl("txtComments");
    DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)selectedRow.FindControl("drpRank");
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When I debug my code I see that txt.Text is equal to "" and drp.SelectedValue is equal to 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't set `CommandArgument` in your `GridView` so it has default empty value.

Comment: What should I write there?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `.CommandArgument` if you didn't set its value in the `GridView`. In fact there is no need to set that `CommandArgument` attribute. So the problem is to identify the row in which the click occurred.

**Update**:
You need to change

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="דרג" CommandName="rank" />
```

to a `templateField`

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRank" runat="server" 
           CausesValidation="false" 
           CommandName="rank" 
           CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' --optional, probably helpful
           Text="Rank"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and then everything should work.

```
//.cs
protected void GrdArticles_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); //wrong. CommandArgument is not set and is empty by default
    GridViewRow selectedRow = ((Control)e.CommandSource /*that is Button*/).NamingContainer;
       //row is found
    //There are three buttons in each row which should be processed differently
    if(e.CommandName == "rank"){
        //do something
    }
    else if(e.CommandName == "addComment"){
        //addComment
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)selectedRow.FindControl("txtComments");//correct
        DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)selectedRow.FindControl("drpRank");//correct
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I changed the code to your suggestion but changed it to GridViewRow selectedRow = ((GridViewRow)e.CommandSource); because I had compilation error. But even than I got a runtime error that it cannot convert 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.'